# Do both parties get the same technology out of a research agreement?

Tags: civilization-5

When a research agreement has finished and you receive your free technology, does your research partner receive the same technology? I would guess that both parties receive one of their respective "next" technologies, which may or may not be the same, right?

Update: **This question has been made obsolete by the June 2011 patch.**  Research agreements now give a tech boost instead of a free tech. Tech boosts start at 50% of the median value of all techs you can research. Can be boosted to 100% if you both start Rationalism and build the Porcelain Tower.

Comment: Wait wait wait... I obviously have not used research agreements enough but... the manual says they just give a 15% research boost. Is that simply wrong? Or is the boost still there and we get a free tech at the end of the agreement? (I'm torn between thinking this is worthy of its own question, and the question being closed as an exact duplicate if I posted it.)

Comment: @Willful I don't know which manual you looked at, but the main point of Research Agreements is that you (and your research partner) receive a random free technology after 30 turns. I'm not sure whether it also provides a 15% boost to traditional research, if so I wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Correct, they are not necessarily the same.  You will receive a random technology from those that are available to you, and they will receive a random one for them.  This does imply that if you are making use of research agreements, you should try not to "skip" techs that are cheap, since you want the research agreement to give you something as "expensive" as possible.

Comment: I have never had a research agreement provide the tech I was working on. Take this anecdotal evidence as you will.

Comment: Great point about not skipping cheap techs. It would be interesting to know how random the choice really is, how big the chance I may receive one of the "cheap" technologies if there are more "expensive" ones waiting. FWIW, most (all?) my research agreements have given me very useful technologies and, @Raven, none the one I was working on at that time (I think the game won't let that happen).

Comment: The game will prioritize techs that you haven't put any turns of research into yet. If you plan ahead, you can research the cheap techs you don't want yet for one turn each, leaving the expensive techs unresearched to increase your chances of receiving them. This is a good reason to avoid signing two RAs on the same turn since it limits your options.